# Raspberry pi not allowing download of image with wget

Tags: linux, camera, wget, raspberry-pi, http-status-code-401

I have an IP camera which requires a login, and so far, I have found no way around it. So I decided to use this:

`http://192.168.1.110:8080/snapshot.cgi?user=[Usernamehere]&pwd=[PasswdHere]&count=3`

When I insert the correct username and password, It works in my browser, It shows me the picture of the webcam stream. I want to make a time-lapse so I have this script:

`wget -O [filenamepath] http://192.168.1.110:8080/snapshot.cgi?user=user&pwd=1234&count=3`

And I get a 401 Unauthorized error in the console. I have no idea what could be going wrong and any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying will only work if the receiving program (in this case, the snapshot.cgi program) is capable of recognizing parameters name `user` and `pwd`, but it's absolutely not a standard.

Probably it will have worked from your browser because were already logged in.  The normal way to add username and password to an url is:

```
http://username:password@192.168.1.110:8080/snapshot.cgi?count=3
```

If that doesn't work, try adding them to the wget command line [as explained in the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget):

```
wget -O [filenamepath] --user=user --password=1234 http://192.168.1.110:8080/snapshot.cgi?count=3
```

ps: you cannot test the url with embedded username and password with IE because some time ago [Microsoft decided to stop supporting that feature.](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;%5BLN%5D;834489)